# Sitecore Handlers

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to create an event handler for sitecore .

I have done following steps.

1. create a dll named "TestEventHandlers" and
2. add its reference in bin folder of my website.
3. Add following line in my web.config events --> event node: `<handler type="TestEventHandlers.EventHandler , TestEventHandlers" method="OnItemSaved"/>`

But i am getting following error:

```
Could not resolve type name: 
TestEventHandlers.EventHandler, TestEventHandlers.EventHandler 
(method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

I am confused about assembly name in type attribute of handler.

Answer (score 10):

> The assembly-qualified name of a type consists of the type name, including its namespace, followed by a comma, followed by the display name of the assembly. [> MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

The assembly-qualified name for you class might look like this:

```
TestEventHandlers.EventHandler, TestEventHandlers
```

Assuming that your dll (assembly) is named `TestEventHandlers` and the class you wrote is called `EventHandler` within the `TestEventHandlers` namespace. In other words, you have this code in your `TestEventHandlers` dll and that dll is in the bin directory of your Sitecore web site.

```
namespace TestEventHandlers
{
    public class EventHandler
    {
        public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 
dll name as- TestEventHandlers.dll , &
class description as - namespace TestEventHandlers.Events{ public class EventHandler{...}} your handler entry shuld be <
handler type="TestEventHandlers.Events.EventHandler , TestEventHandlers" method="OnItemSaved"/>